# undefined reference to `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs

Tags: c++, hadoop, java-native-interface

Here is the build log,anyone can help?

```
/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/lib/native/libhdfs.a(jni_helper.c.o): In function `getGlobalJNIEnv':

/data/elmerzeng/install/packages/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/jni_helper.c:446: undefined reference to `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs'

/data/elmerzeng/install/packages/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/jni_helper.c:505: undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'

/data/elmerzeng/install/packages/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/jni_helper.c:505: undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'

/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/lib/native/libhdfs.a(jni_helper.c.o): In function `getJNIEnv':

/data/elmerzeng/install/packages/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/jni_helper.c:570: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'

/data/elmerzeng/install/packages/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/jni_helper.c:579: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'

/data/elmerzeng/install/packages/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/jni_helper.c:598: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You did not link to the necessary libraries, therefore an implementation for hadoop and pthread functions could not be found. Read up on how to link to libraries with your toolchain and which libraries to link to from the documentation or lib folder of hadoop.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have got it!